# How do I install a chef knife plugin/gem with the omnibus installer?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I've been struggling to find the documentation of how to do this.

No luck at:

- http://docs.opscode.com/plugin_knife.html
- http://docs.opscode.com/chef/knife_plugins.html

Answer (score 7):

sudo /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install THE_NAME_OF_THE_GEM

Comment: You may need `--no-rdoc` and `--no-ri`.